# Teradata while loop giving me "query invalid" error, even when doing nothing

Tags: sql, teradata

So my inside update statement runs. The logic here should dictate that this loop runs once and then ends. Instead I get a "query invalid" error. When I comment out the update it fails too.

```
BEGIN    ---each update would only change some to BBT that were not already. We can cycle through the last 3 tech titles
    DECLARE i INT;
    SET i=1;
    WHILE i<2 DO
BEGIN

    UPDATE a
FROM DLBIFO.ML_BBT a,
 (SELECT DimFsclMthSk, hrnum, AsscId, TitlNm, caldt, 'BBT' AS ScrcrdInd   --006
FROM (
SELECT tech.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY hrnum, DimFsclMthSk ORDER BY caldt DESC) AS num, DimFsclMthSk, caldt
FROM XBITblsV.DimEmployee tech,
 (SELECT DimDateSk, DimFsclMthSk, caldt
        FROM XBITblsV.DimDate
        WHERE DimDateSk >= 20170322
        AND DimDateSk <= 20170523) tdim
WHERE tdim.caldt >= tech.effdttm
    AND tdim.caldt < expdttm
    AND DimEmployeeSk <> -1
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY hrnum, DimFsclMthSk ORDER BY effdttm DESC) = i
) a, 
  XBIMdmV.MdmTechOpsScrcdTitle b
WHERE a.caldt >= busstartdt AND a.caldt < COALESCE(busenddt, DATE'2099-01-01') 
AND TitlNm = b.techtitle) BBT 
SET ScrcrdInd = BBT.ScrcrdInd
WHERE a.DimFsclMthSk = bbt.DimFsclMthSk
    AND a.AsscId = bbt.AsscId      ;--006     
/*SELECT TOP 1 * FROM DLBIFO.ML_BBT;*/
SET i=i+1;      

END;
    end while;  
   END;
```

Comment: Is this part of a Stored Procedure? Outside of an SP BEGIN/DECLARE/WHILE are invalid syntax.

Comment: You are a saint sir.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your `set i = i + 1;` between the `END` and `END WHILE`.